# HOW TO INSERT DATE WITH DOTS FORMAT IN SQL

Tags: sql, database, dataframe

I want to insert a date like 31.12.2021 in SQL, and I get something wrong
what should I write to make it works?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us your current INSERT attempt.

Comment: Please show what you are currently doing and the definition of your datatable

Comment: 31.12.2021 is not a valid date format in mysql or sql server but if quoted you can store in a character column,

Comment: @P.Salmon, don't encourage storing dates in char columns.

Comment: `YYYY.MM.DD` should be valid... for mysql at least. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html `Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts`

Answer (score 0):

In `sql-server` you can use `convert(varchar, [date you want to convert], 104)` if your column is a date datatype as shown in [microsoft sql-server cast and convert docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).